# FullSimplify not working when simplifying a complex number

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

Here is a snippet of the code I am working on, which requires me to get the Real part of the Harmonic Oscillator wavefunction.

```
p = (a (-3 + 2 a^2) E^(-105 I - a^2/2))/Sqrt[3];
FullSimplify[p, Element[a, Reals]];
ExpToTrig[(a (-3 + 2 a^2) E^(-105 I - a^2/2))/Sqrt[3]]
```

Obviously, the only imaginary part present in the equations is (I) itself. I cannot understand how to get the I outside the Sine and Cosines. Because the output I get is

```
(a (-3 + 2 a^2) (Cos[105 - (I a^2)/2] -I Sin[105 - (I a^2)/2]))/Sqrt[3]
```

Comment: Have a look at [ComplexExpand](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html?q=ComplexExpand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = (a (-3 + 2 a^2) E^(-105 I - a^2/2))/Sqrt[3]

{r, i} = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[p] // ReIm, a ∈ Reals]
```

$$\left\{\frac{a \left(2 a^2-3\right) e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} \cos (105)}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{a \left(3-2 a^2\right) e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} \sin (105)}{\sqrt{3}}\right\}$$

```
(r + I i // TrigToExp // Simplify) == p
```

> True

Comment: If you wanted degrees, then write `105 Degree` instead.